# Browser displays blank page after switching between tabs in a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp in a 32-bit WPF application. I use CefSharp as a document viewer, which displays local HTML and PDF files. Each Browser instance is embedded in a Tab (using WPF TabControl).

With version 63.0.3 everything worked fine. After updating to 73.1.130, I encounter the following issue: **after opening some tabs and switching between them, the browser displays a blank page in all tabs.**

Note: in WPF switching from and back to a tab results in a reload of all controls inside the tab.

The only way I found to fix the issue is downgrading to 63.0.3 again.

CefSharp is initialized in App.xaml.cs:

```
var cefSettings = new CefSettings()
{
  LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Verbose
};
var customScheme = new CefCustomScheme
{
  SchemeName = CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName,
  SchemeHandlerFactory = new CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory(),
  IsCSPBypassing = true
};
cefSettings.RegisterScheme(customScheme);
Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
```

The browser is embedded like this:

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser
    x:Name="WebBrowser" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Address="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Title="{Binding Titel, Mode=OneWay}"
    AllowDrop="True"
    WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

Here's the first few lines of debug.log:

```
[0626/113449.874:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(123)] Could not get the download directory.
[0626/113449.898:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(184)] 0C68AB50: set chrome proxy config service to 11372508
[0626/113449.900:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Argon2018' log
[0626/113449.900:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Argon2019' log
[0626/113449.900:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Argon2020' log
[0626/113449.901:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Argon2021' log
[0626/113449.901:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Xenon2019' log
[0626/113449.901:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Xenon2020' log
[0626/113449.901:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Xenon2021' log
[0626/113449.902:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Xenon2022' log
[0626/113449.902:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Aviator' log
[0626/113449.902:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Icarus' log
[0626/113449.902:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Pilot' log
[0626/113449.903:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Rocketeer' log
[0626/113449.903:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Google 'Skydiver' log
[0626/113449.903:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Cloudflare 'Nimbus2018' Log
[0626/113449.903:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Cloudflare 'Nimbus2019' Log
[0626/113449.903:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Cloudflare 'Nimbus2020' Log
[0626/113449.903:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Cloudflare 'Nimbus2021' Log
[0626/113449.904:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Log Server
[0626/113449.904:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Log Server 2
[0626/113449.904:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Yeti2018 Log
[0626/113449.904:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Yeti2019 Log
[0626/113449.904:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Yeti2020 Log
[0626/113449.904:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Yeti2021 Log
[0626/113449.905:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Yeti2022 Log
[0626/113449.905:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Nessie2018 Log
[0626/113449.905:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Nessie2019 Log
[0626/113449.906:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Nessie2020 Log
[0626/113449.906:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Nessie2021 Log
[0626/113449.906:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: DigiCert Nessie2022 Log
[0626/113449.906:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Venafi Gen2 CT log
[0626/113449.907:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Sectigo 'Sabre' CT log
[0626/113449.907:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Sectigo 'Mammoth' CT log
[0626/113449.909:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Symantec 'Sirius' log
[0626/113449.910:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: StartCom log
[0626/113449.910:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: WoSign log
[0626/113449.910:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Izenpe log
[0626/113449.911:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: CNNIC CT log
[0626/113449.911:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Venafi log
[0626/113449.911:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Symantec 'Vega' log
[0626/113449.913:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Certly.IO log
[0626/113449.914:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(65)] Adding CT log: Symantec log
[0626/113459.819:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/9c44150b-b047-4417-aca5-0cb7194a6a52.pdf
[0626/113459.835:VERBOSE1:cookie_monster.cc(1755)] WARNING: Unsupported cookie scheme: local
[0626/113459.890:INFO:cpu_info.cc(49)] Available number of cores: 8
[0626/113459.929:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A71AAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.6ms stack: HeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: EagerSweeping reason: ForcedGC
[0626/113459.941:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A71AAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.33ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: LazySweeping reason: PreciseGC
[0626/113459.960:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3756)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[0626/113459.967:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3756)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[0626/113459.971:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(152)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[0626/113459.982:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(94)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  2B141990
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[0626/113459.983:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(94)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[0626/113459.984:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(345)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[0626/113459.998:VERBOSE1:html_plugin_element.cc(605)] EMBED id="plugin" Plugin URL: "local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/9c44150b-b047-4417-aca5-0cb7194a6a52.pdf"
[0626/113459.998:VERBOSE1:html_plugin_element.cc(606)] Loaded URL: "local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/9c44150b-b047-4417-aca5-0cb7194a6a52.pdf"
[0626/113500.015:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.html
[0626/113500.154:INFO:cpu_info.cc(49)] Available number of cores: 8
[0626/113500.178:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A91AAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.57ms stack: HeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: EagerSweeping reason: ForcedGC
[0626/113500.192:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A91AAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.5ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: LazySweeping reason: PreciseGC
[0626/113500.198:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3756)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[0626/113500.208:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3756)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[0626/113500.209:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-error-screen/viewer-error-screen.html
[0626/113500.210:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-page-indicator/viewer-page-indicator.html
[0626/113500.211:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-page-selector/viewer-page-selector.html
[0626/113500.211:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-password-screen/viewer-password-screen.html
[0626/113500.212:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-pdf-toolbar/viewer-pdf-toolbar.html
[0626/113500.212:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-zoom-toolbar/viewer-zoom-toolbar.html
[0626/113500.213:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/shared-vars.html
[0626/113500.213:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/css/text_defaults_md.css
[0626/113500.214:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.css
[0626/113500.214:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/pdf_fitting_type.js
[0626/113500.217:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/toolbar_manager.js
[0626/113500.218:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/viewport.js
[0626/113500.219:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/open_pdf_params_parser.js
[0626/113500.219:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/navigator.js
[0626/113500.219:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/viewport_scroller.js
[0626/113500.220:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/zoom_manager.js
[0626/113500.222:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/gesture_detector.js
[0626/113500.222:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/pdf_scripting_api.js
[0626/113500.222:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/js/assert.js
[0626/113500.223:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/js/load_time_data.js
[0626/113500.223:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/js/util.js
[0626/113500.223:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/js/promise_resolver.js
[0626/113500.224:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/browser_api.js
[0626/113500.224:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/metrics.js
[0626/113500.224:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/pdf_viewer.js
[0626/113500.225:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/main.js
[0626/113500.225:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 for more details.", source:  (0)
[0626/113500.233:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/html/polymer.html
[0626/113500.234:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/cr_dialog/cr_dialog.html
[0626/113500.235:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/hidden_style_css.html
[0626/113500.236:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/paper_button_style_css.html
[0626/113500.236:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-button/paper-button.html
[0626/113500.237:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-error-screen/viewer-error-screen.js
[0626/113500.238:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/css/roboto.css
[0626/113500.238:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/html/assert.html
[0626/113500.239:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/html/util.html
[0626/113500.239:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-page-indicator/viewer-page-indicator.js
[0626/113500.239:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/cr_input/cr_input.html
[0626/113500.239:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-page-selector/viewer-page-selector.js
[0626/113500.240:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/shared_style_css.html
[0626/113500.241:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/shared_vars_css.html
[0626/113500.241:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-password-screen/viewer-password-screen.js
[0626/113500.242:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html
[0626/113500.242:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-progress/paper-progress.html
[0626/113500.242:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/icons.html
[0626/113500.242:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/icons.html
[0626/113500.243:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A91AAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.21ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: IncrementalMarking sweeping: LazySweeping reason: IncrementalIdleGC
[0626/113500.244:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-bookmarks-content/viewer-bookmarks-content.html
[0626/113500.244:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-toolbar-dropdown/viewer-toolbar-dropdown.html
[0626/113500.244:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-zoom-toolbar/viewer-zoom-button.html
[0626/113500.245:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-zoom-toolbar/viewer-zoom-toolbar.js
[0626/113500.245:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-styles/color.html
[0626/113500.245:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-pdf-toolbar/viewer-pdf-toolbar.js
[0626/113500.249:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/js/polymer_config.js
[0626/113500.258:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(152)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[0626/113500.258:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(94)] Created context:
  extension id:           mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai
  frame:                  2CD01990
  URL:                    
  context_type:           BLESSED_EXTENSION
  effective extension id: mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai
  effective context type: BLESSED_EXTENSION
[0626/113500.259:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(94)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[0626/113500.261:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(345)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[0626/113500.262:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/polymer/polymer.html
[0626/113500.264:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/cr_icons_css.html
[0626/113500.266:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button-light.html
[0626/113500.266:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/cr_dialog/cr_dialog.js
[0626/113500.267:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-icon/iron-icon.html
[0626/113500.268:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-behaviors/paper-inky-focus-behavior.html
[0626/113500.269:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-styles/default-theme.html
[0626/113500.269:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button-extracted.js
[0626/113500.270:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html
[0626/113500.270:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-range-behavior/iron-range-behavior.html
[0626/113500.271:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-progress/paper-progress-extracted.js
[0626/113500.272:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html
[0626/113500.272:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-bookmark/viewer-bookmark.html
[0626/113500.272:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-bookmarks-content/viewer-bookmarks-content.js
[0626/113500.273:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-toolbar-dropdown/viewer-toolbar-dropdown.js
[0626/113500.273:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-fab/paper-fab.html
[0626/113500.275:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-zoom-toolbar/viewer-zoom-button.js
[0626/113500.275:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-behaviors/paper-button-behavior.html
[0626/113500.275:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-styles/element-styles/paper-material-styles.html
[0626/113500.276:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-button/paper-button-extracted.js
[0626/113500.276:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/js/assert.js
[0626/113500.276:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/js/util.js
[0626/113500.277:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/cr_input/cr_input_style_css.html
[0626/113500.277:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/cr_elements/cr_input/cr_input.js
[0626/113500.278:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A91AAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.14ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: IncrementalMarking sweeping: LazySweeping reason: IncrementalIdleGC
[0626/113500.278:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/polymer/polymer-extracted.js
[0626/113500.288:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-range-behavior/iron-range-behavior-extracted.js
[0626/113500.289:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-behaviors/paper-ripple-behavior.html
[0626/113500.290:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button-light-extracted.js
[0626/113500.291:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-meta/iron-meta.html
[0626/113500.291:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg-extracted.js
[0626/113500.291:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html
[0626/113500.292:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/elements/viewer-bookmark/viewer-bookmark.js
[0626/113500.292:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-fab/paper-fab-extracted.js
[0626/113500.293:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-behaviors/iron-button-state.html
[0626/113500.293:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-behaviors/paper-button-behavior-extracted.js
[0626/113500.293:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-styles/shadow.html
[0626/113500.294:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-icon/iron-icon-extracted.js
[0626/113500.306:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-behaviors/paper-inky-focus-behavior-extracted.js
[0626/113500.310:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-behaviors/paper-ripple-behavior-extracted.js
[0626/113500.310:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-meta/iron-meta-extracted.js
[0626/113500.311:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior.html
[0626/113500.311:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/paper-ripple/paper-ripple-extracted.js
[0626/113500.312:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html
[0626/113500.312:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-behaviors/iron-button-state-extracted.js
[0626/113500.314:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior-extracted.js
[0626/113500.316:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/polymer/v1_0/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state-extracted.js
[0626/113500.453:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/roboto/roboto-regular.woff2
[0626/113500.510:VERBOSE1:html_plugin_element.cc(605)] EMBED id="plugin" Plugin URL: "local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/9c44150b-b047-4417-aca5-0cb7194a6a52.pdf"
[0626/113500.510:VERBOSE1:html_plugin_element.cc(606)] Loaded URL: "local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/9c44150b-b047-4417-aca5-0cb7194a6a52.pdf"
[0626/113500.623:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/7546c25a-fb45-45c1-b316-2acbdd01155e
[0626/113500.626:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: chrome://resources/roboto/roboto-medium.woff2
[0626/113500.689:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3756)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[0626/113500.777:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A91AAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.69ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: IncrementalMarking sweeping: LazySweeping reason: IncrementalIdleGC
[0626/113501.926:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/db8fc5b1-9c66-426d-b27d-b998edb5a890.pdf
[0626/113501.927:VERBOSE1:cookie_monster.cc(1755)] WARNING: Unsupported cookie scheme: local
[0626/113502.044:INFO:cpu_info.cc(49)] Available number of cores: 8
[0626/113502.067:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A8CAAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.86ms stack: HeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: EagerSweeping reason: ForcedGC
[0626/113502.079:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1585)] [state:0A8CAAF0] CollectGarbage: time: 0.3ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: LazySweeping reason: PreciseGC
[0626/113502.092:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/db8fc5b1-9c66-426d-b27d-b998edb5a890.pdf
[0626/113502.092:VERBOSE1:cookie_monster.cc(1755)] WARNING: Unsupported cookie scheme: local
[0626/113502.096:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3756)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[0626/113502.104:VERBOSE1:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3756)] GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil supported.
[0626/113502.107:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(152)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[0626/113502.116:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(94)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  216E1990
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[0626/113502.117:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(94)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[0626/113502.117:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(345)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[0626/113502.127:VERBOSE1:html_plugin_element.cc(605)] EMBED id="plugin" Plugin URL: "local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/db8fc5b1-9c66-426d-b27d-b998edb5a890.pdf"
[0626/113502.127:VERBOSE1:html_plugin_element.cc(606)] Loaded URL: "local://c/DMS/Dokumente/2019/06/db8fc5b1-9c66-426d-b27d-b998edb5a890.pdf"
[0626/113502.134:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(485)] Num tracked contexts: 0
[0626/113502.136:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(152)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
```

Comment: This is a known issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to amaitland (see comments) it's an issue in version 73 - https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2779. Version 71 doesn't have this issue.